# Create powershell environment variables with makefile, and accessing them with python os.environ

Tags: python, powershell, makefile, environment-variables, python-poetry

With VSCode, I'm accessing to a python project that have a makefile like this:

```
VARIABLES = VAR1="text1" \
    VAR2="text2" \
    VAR3="text3"

.PHONY: run
run:
    $(VARIABLES) poetry run python -m start.app
```

I am on a windows machine, with "make" installed on powershell by chocholately.
Launching the command `make --version` prints:

```
GNU Make 4.3
Built for Windows32
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

BUT the `run` command is not compatible with powershell (at best of my understanding). I think the solution is to rewrite the `run` command.
Given the fact that the code in pythom will access the variable this way

```
import os
print(os.environ["var1"])
```

I'm trying to solve this by having the `run` command using the powershell command `$env:var1 = "true"` before running the poetry command

Am i on the right trak? How can i achive this? Is there a smarter solution?

I tried googling with various key search but it seems i cannot find the answer or other solution to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to have those variables set *only* when invoking the run target?  If you're willing to have them set for all targets you can just export them from make itself:

```
export VAR1 = text1
export VAR2 = text2
export VAR3 = text3

.PHONY: run
run:
        poetry run python -m start.app
```

Actually I guess you could also use target-specific exported variables:

```
.PHONY: run
run: export VAR1 = text1
run: export VAR2 = text2
run: export VAR3 = text3
run:
        poetry run python -m start.app
```

Comment: This is it! I had tried this solution before, but i was testing it in the powershell terminal, using "echo" & similiar and send me off-track. But sending this directly in the cose it proved right.